# SSH like, simple vpn for Win2012 -> 2012 for SQL Log shipping?

Tags: windows

On linux, you can fire up a quick and dirty port redirection via ssh, and do scp etc.

One or two commands on each side, and you are cooking. Chron job to check it is up and restart it if nec.

E.g. on linux I can do this:

```
ssh -f user@other-server.com -L 2000:other-server.com:25 -N
```

And voila. My local port 2000 is now routed to the remote server's port 25. No wizards. No mucking around (at least on the "client" side of the story).

What is the simple, direct, way to do this on windows?

The Windows VPN docs I have found so far are .... long.

What is the fast way to get a secure tunnel for file copies up across data centers (no common domain, etc).

Win2012.

Comment: Use the same technology as you would if you were doing it the right way on linux: IPSec.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the same command you listed in the Cygwin bash (or other) shell.  [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) is a Linux-like environment for Windows that includes bash and ssh.

Comment: I know I can add cygwin, or third party ssh stuff to win server. Isn't there something that is in the OS that is as usable (or close to as usable)?